# How to use a subdomain for my Azure B2C custom policies instead of using the default B2C domain?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

To be consistent with our company brand, I would like to use our subdomain myaccount.example.com instead of using .b2clogin.com/.onmicrosoft.com.  I've seen references that it can be done, but I don't see any examples.  Are there any examples, documentation or tutorials on how to do this?

Comment: This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain) might help

Answer (score -1):

I found another [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/add-custom-domain-name-azure-active-directory/) that was similar to the one mentioned by Tiago Brenck.

***Here are the brief steps.***

1.Add a custom domain name to Azure AD

[image]
On the proseware.com page, copy the DNS information.
[image]

2.Add your DNS information to the domain registrar
[image]
[image]

3.Verify your custom domain in Azure
[image]

Comment: This doesn’t achieve anything in B2C tenant.